# How to expose graphql field with different name

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am exploring GraphQL and would like to know if there is any way of renaming the response field for example i have a POJO with these field

```
class POJO {
  Long id;
  String name;
}
```

GraphQL query:

```
type POJO {
  id: Long
  name: String
}
```

My response is something like this

```
{
  "POJO" {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "abc"
  }
}
```

Can i rename the name field to something like userName so that my response is below

```
{
  "POJO" {
    "id": 123,
    "userName": "abc"
  }
}
```

Comment: The traditional way to do this would be in a (custom) resolver. So the argument value in the query would be `userName` and in your resolver you look up the `name` value. This would even work if all you could modify was an existing schema. See [Schema Delegation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-delegation/) on the Apollo documentation.

Answer (score 117):

You can use [GraphQL Aliases](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to modify individual keys in the JSON response.

If this is your original query

```
query {
  POJO {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

you can introduce a GraphQL alias `userName` for the field `name` like so:

```
query {
  POJO {
    id
    userName: name
  }
}
```

You can also use GraphQL aliases to use the same query or mutation field multiple times in the same GraphQL operation. This gets especially interesting when using field parameters:

```
query {
  first: POJO(first: 1) {
    id
    name
  }

  second: POJO(first: 1, skip: 1) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to change my query, i was thinking if i can map that field to different name before returning the result from backend, is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just rename the field directly in the schema then?

Comment: I think this is controlled by client side. But what if expose the fields need transform by server side?

Comment: That's essentially the same question @AmitKumar asked, and my answer is the same.

Comment: This clears my issue for having custom field name on client side. Thanks !

Comment: So glad this exists for those that like to follow a singular naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old but following code is used for renaming the field:

```
public class ProductReviewType: ObjectGraphType<ProductReview>
{
    public ProductReviewType()
    {
        Field(x => x.ProductReviewId, type: typeof(IdGraphType)).Description("some desc here");
        Field(x => x.ProductId).Description("some desc here");
        Field("reviewername", x => x.ReviewerName).Description("some desc here");            
        Field("reviewdate",x => x.ReviewDate).Description("some desc here");
        Field("emailaddress", x => x.EmailAddress).Description("some desc here");
        Field("rating", x => x.Rating).Description("some desc here");
        Field("comments",x => x.Comments).Description("some desc here");
        Field("modifieddate", x => x.ModifiedDate).Description("some desc here");
    }

}
```

In the above code, modifieddate would be the field name for property "ModifiedDate".

Comment: Just as a note, it would appear this renaming strategy does not work for InputObjectGraphType (types used on mutations).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like GraphQLName annotation can help.

Example from [documentation](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations) :
"Additionally, @GraphQLName can be used to override field name. You can use @GraphQLDescription to set a description."

These can also be used for field parameters:

```
public String field(@GraphQLName("val") String value) {
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is: **how are you creating the schema in the first place**? There's no intrinsic connection between Java and GraphQL types - they are completely unrelated unless you correlate them. So you can name the fields any way you want in the schema, and make a resolver (`DataFetcher`) that gets the value from anywhere (thus any POJO field too).

If you're using a tool to generate the schema from Java types ([graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-annotations), [graphql-spqr](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr) etc), then use that tool's facilities to drive the mapping. Both the mentioned tools allow customizing the mapping via annotations. GraphQL-SPQR enables the same via external configuration as well.

If you clarify your question further, I'll be able to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, if you are using the Field(x=>x.Example) syntax:

```
Field(x => x.Example).Name("exampleNewName");
```

This will make your query go from this:

```
query{
  fake{
    example
   }
}
```

to this:

```
query{
  fake{
    exampleNewName
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GraphQL Aliases to modify individual keys in the JSON response.

If this is your original query

query {
POJO {
id
name
}
}
you can introduce a GraphQL alias userName for the field name like so:

query {
POJO {
id
userName: name
}
}
You can also use GraphQL aliases to use the same query or mutation field multiple times in the same GraphQL operation. This gets especially interesting when using field parameters:

query {
first: POJO(first: 1) {
id
name
}

second: POJO(first: 1, skip: 1) {
id
name
}
}