# How to map graphQL query property to different response property?

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-config

I have a graphQL `type` defined in a `.graphql` file for a nestjs schema first application. The type is:

```
type address {
  id: String
  Title: String
  Url: String
}
```

Now, using nestjs I have a resolver function as

```
@Query('address')
async getAll(): Promise<any> {
  return await this.addressService.getAll();
}
```

The result from the `await this.addressService.getAll()` is an array of objects with the properties having `_` in them like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    address_title: 'title',
    address_url: 'url'

  }
]
```

I am also using `@nestjs/graphql` library for the `@Query`, `@ResolveField` and such. My problem is, how can I map the response properties to the graphql properties that I have written as a SDL in the `.graphql` file in nestjs framework? Is there any way we can map the graphql query properties to the result properties using nestjs?

I looked at the graphql alias, also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883075/how-to-expose-graphql-field-with-different-name) but that is not useful for me. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use direct approach:

```js
@Query('address')
getAll(): Promise<any> {
  return this.addressService.getAll().map(this.addressMapper);
}

private addressMapper(address: any): address {
  return {id: address.id, Title: address.address_title, Url: address_url};
}
```

Or use NestJS [pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes).